# ReactJS - Passing state from a toggle button to hide a Div

Tags: reactjs, toggle, state, react-props

In a React project, I have a toggle button that shows and hides some info to the user. Now I want to connect a third part to the toggle.

For instance, a div is shown on when the page loads, then the toggle button is clicked then I want that to hide.

I need to know, how do I pass the state from one component to another to show visibility.

I have created a REPL here:

https://repl.it/repls/AcceptableLoyalApplicationsuite

How do I pass the state to know to hide/show based on users clicking?

Cheers!

Edit:

So I need to check the state to show/hide the component.

```
if statement or state check to show / hide 
<Component />
```

Comment: It would be best if you add your code here. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define state & function in parent component like mentioned below and pass to child components.

Just change these two components

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visibility: false
  };
  handleToggleVisibility = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ visibility: !prevState.visibility }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Test />
          <Button
            visibility={this.state.visibility}
            handleToggleVisibility={this.handleToggleVisibility}
          />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Button.js

```
 export default class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <em>I have another Div with the className of iNeedToHide</em>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.props.handleToggleVisibility}>
          {this.props.visibility ? "Hide details" : "Show details"}
        </button>
        {this.props.visibility && (
          <div>
            <p>
              Hey. These are some details you can now see! When you see me the
              div above called iNeedToHide needs to be hidden! But how?! How do
              I pass that state?!
            </p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Live demo of your working code [Live](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-frog-z5fbg)

Comment: Hey thanks for this, maybe I didn't explain myself properly but I want to leave the button as it but almost have an if statement checking to see if the state is visible or not and then showing/hiding a component. See my edit above!

Comment: @user3502952 check sandbox now... is this you want?

Comment: That is good but how would I do the same {this.state.visibility && <Content />} to hide a component? Thank you sir!

Comment: @user3502952 here based on button toggle it's hiding component.... what else you want now?

Comment: So I have a component that is already showing the component when it loads, when the button is pressed I want it to hide basically the reverse of  {this.state.visibility && <Content />} so hide the component on click - almost like  {!this.state.visibility && <Content />} ? I do not know - cheers!

Comment: @user3502952 just make state visibility true for that...you can check live demo now.

Comment: @user3502952 please accept/vote for this if it's helpful for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205456/discussion-between-user3502952-and-vahid-akhtar).

Comment: Thank you for your help
But this is not really the solution I was looking for as I already have that button working but it is an additional component just to hide when the button is clicked - does that make sense.  I need to leave the original buttons but just want want to hide based on the button being toggled / clicked - Thank you for all your help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205492/discussion-between-tired-man-and-vahid-akhtar).